# PHPStorm + XDebug , hangs when trying to enter method

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

My `PHP` storm debugger hangs when reaching a specific method via `xdebug` and does not continue the process either if I try to step over or step in the method.

My environment:

*Dev PC:*

1. Windows 7
2. PHP Storm
3. Chrome as browser + XDebug Helper extension to trigger the debug .

*Dev Server:*

1. Linux Mint
2. LAMP
3. XDebug
4. Magento 1.8

Does someone has experience with this case, or similar ones?

Comment: Does it run properly on your server OR pc ?

Comment: On server and I debug from Pc , I debug all the time , there is one method which it does hangs in for some reason...